# If $| f(a)| \leq1$ for all $a\in S$, then $\Vert \nabla f(x)\Vert<4$ for some $x\in\text{Int}(S)$.

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

Let $S$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with centre $(0,0,0)$. Let $f$ be a differentiable function in a neighbourhood of $S$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that, if $|f(a)| \leq1$ for all $a\in S$, then there exists $x\in\text{int}(S)$ with $\Vert \nabla f(x)\Vert<4$, where $\nabla=(\partial/\partial x,\partial/\partial y,\partial/\partial z)$ is the gradient.

I'd like a HINT, not a complete answer.

Comment: I edited the question just a bit. Tell me if I missed your meaning. Also, by $\nabla f$ do you mean the matrix norm of $Df?$

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, I made a mistake formulating the problem. The function $f$ goes from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I edited the question.

Comment: Just argue by contradiction and use some forms of mean value theorem.

Comment: @Arctic Char. The forms I know of the mean value theorem are: $$f(x)-f(y)=\nabla f(\xi)\cdot (x-y),$$ $$f(x+h)-f(x)=(\int_0^1 \nabla f(x+th)\,dt)\cdot h.$$ Assuming that $\Vert \nabla f(x)\Vert\geq 4$ for all $x\in S$, I don't see how I can lower-bound $\Vert \nabla f(\xi)\cdot (x-y)\Vert$ or $\Vert \int_0^1 \nabla f(x+th)\,dt)\cdot h\Vert$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky. I will try to give just a few hints. First, if $f(0,0,0)=-1$, then you're done (why?). So suppose $f(0,0,0)>-1$. Now define

$$g(x,y,z) = f(x,y,z) - 2(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$

Argue that $g$ attains its maximum over $S$ at an interior point, and complete the proof from here.

Comment: I understood. If $f(0,0,0)=-1$, then $(0,0,0)$ is a local máximum, so $\Vert\nabla f(0,0,0)\Vert=0<4$. Suppose $f(0,0,0)>-1$. Let $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S$ be the máximum of $g$ in $S$. If $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is at the boundary of $S$, then $g(x_0,y_0,z_0)=f(x_0,y_0,z_0)-2\leq 1-2=-1<f(0,0,0)=g(0,0,0)$, which is a contradiction. Then $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in\text{Int}(S)$ and therefore $(0,0,0)=\nabla g(x_0,y_0,z_0)=\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)-4(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Hence, $\Vert \nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\Vert=4\Vert (x_0,y_0,z_0)\Vert<4$.

Comment: @jxm   That's perfect!

Comment: Nice solution! $\,$